# Excel does not start correctly when impersonating users running as a service

Tags: c#, excel, winapi, windows-services

Running Excel as a service is not recommended, I know. :-)

Problem: Starting Excel from a windows service does work fine. Even multiple instances can work side by side seamlessly. The problem arises with the necessity to run queries against Analysis Services. Unfortunately the user Id/ password properties of an Analysis Services Connection are not used when not using http protocol. MSAS Ole Db Connection pass over the user of the running process. This makes it necessary to not only start Excel from a Service but even do impersonation beforehand. (if anybody has a better idea here, you are welcome!)

To let Excel be impersonated Process.Start in c# does not work anymore as it uses CreateProcessWithLogonW under the hood which leads to an Access Denied error message when running as a service while trying to load the user profile.

Steps:

1. LogonUser
2. Impersonate
3. LoadUserProfile
4. GetEnvironmentBlock
5. CreateProcessAsUser

The problem after all isnt that Excel doesnt start at all or gives error messages, it just doesnt have any windows. Threads are available but no windows to iterate.

Is there anybody out there having experience with that?

Note:

1. If code is necessary, I am happy to add it, it is bunch so I didn't add it so far.
2. The code runs fine, Excel will start seamlessly when I do not impersonate but retrieve the token from the current process and create a primary token out of it
3. Does anybody know how to find out why Excel hangs? Neither eventlog, nor procmon or procexp show any useful information.
4. logon always work without error messages (I tried LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE as well as _SERVICE as well as others)
5. For impersonation I used ImpersonateLoggedOnUser as well as the c# variant without different behavior

thanks.

Comment: Check the session id of the process in the Taskbar manager? It shouldn't be 0 and process id should be the same as winlogon.exe process. Other wise you'll not see anything as UI though the threads and process will run fine.

Comment: Almost certainly, it's *trying* to show UI of some kind and failing. That's one of the primary reasons given for why its not supported for services - Excel was written as a user application and expects to be able to prompt the user for input. You *may* be able to work around this by ensuring that every user who *will* be impersonated has logged onto this machine at least once, directly, and has started Excel (to get past any initial setup activities).

Comment: @vendettamit: the session id has to 0 as it should run as a service. When running under the session of a certain user it will not possible to control/ access the process anymore.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The odd thing is that it does work fine when the system impersonates/ loads user profile and the like. When I do it programmatically it just fails. It even fails when I use the already logged on account and try to impersonate it again (e.g. with LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS). Certainly prerequiste is to open Excel once before it can be executed like this - DCOM/ printer are configured.

Comment: All I can really recommend is a redesign. You yourself acknowledge in your question that it's not supported. So find another way to achieve the overall goals that doesn't include "run Excel from the service".

Comment: @da5id You can still run the service if it's session id is not 0. The 0 session means it's a system service and not user service. System services are meant to run in background and they are not supposed to interact with UI in any way. Hope you're getting my point.

Comment: @Damien: Unfortunately there is no other way from business point of view. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Vendettamit: I got your point. I tried to make Excel running in an user session but without luck.
Thanks anyway!